# Visual Code Search and Compare view is not visible

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I just updated the visual code on Ubuntu 20.04 and the search and compare view is no more visible.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how can I make it visible. I did google search but didn't get much help.

Answer (score 11):

If anyone has run into this problem recently, there was a recent change (Version 14.0.0) that moved "Search & Compare" to the new "GitLens Inspect" section.

> Rearranges the GitLens views for greater focus and productivity, including the new GitLens Inspect and moved some of our views from Source Control into either GitLens or GitLens Inspect.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/eamodio.gitlens/changelog#user-content-%5B14.0.0%5D---2023-06-14

Comment: Is there any way to return this to the old position? There's extra clicks now to get into Search&Compare.

Answer (score 3):

Open the command box using Ctrl + Shift + P and search for Compare Working Tree, select the first option (ie. GitLens: Compare Working Tree with...) After selecting this, it will start showing the SEARCH & COMPARE tab.

[image]

[image]